# analysing video stream for conditions

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-video-indexer

Not entirely new to azure, but new to the Media Services available on azure. I am looking for suggestion on what azure components I should consider to build a solution to analyze video for certain conditions.

(e.g. 1) Presence of a human - Yes/No, 2) alert if no human presence detected for a certain number of minutes, 3) confirmation if identified human is wearing a uniform or not, etc. )

I have built a somewhat similar on-premise solution in the past using OpenCV & some open source ML libraries, not sure what azure services I can use if this will be running in Azure.
I can live stream this to azure and am not looking for an edge solution.

I looked up azure video indexer and it looks promising, but probably more tuned for audio analysis rather then image frame analysis.
suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Azure video indexer is optimized for files, not streams, but is capable of meeting the requirement since it detect faces and people (in advanced preset).

Regarding uniform or not, this is not supported in video indexer at the moment but ability to detect cloth color will come in the future.

Comment: so, what else can i use for streams ? can I not write & integrate my own ML for detecting uniform ?

Answer (score 1):

By fragmenting the video, Azure Video Indexer provides a near live solution. It means there will be a few minutes delay, so it depends on how time-sensitive your requirements are.
Regarding your second question, it will be possible to customize a model to identify specific uniforms in a few months. When the bounding boxes of the uniforms match the bounding boxes of the detected people, you can identify if a person is wearing a uniform.